# How to create a packing slip?

Tags: 7, commerce

We want to be able to print a packing slip from a completed order.

I see that the line items is a view but how can I create a new page or tab on the order page to display a clean packing slip?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this list of order printing and order invoicing modules](https://drupal.org/node/1535498).

I think [Commerce Billy](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_billy) looks promising, but I haven't tried it out.

[Commerce Order2Pdf](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_order2pdf) is another promising module, but I'm not sure how customizable it is.

I am currently building a custom module to handle my own packing slip requirement.  I'm building to a template, and have found [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/) to be quite useful for this.

If you're comfortable with custom module development, I'd think that FPDF is the way to go, but you'll just need to write a lot of PHP to build a template, and then use Drupal Commerce API and/or custom database queries to load in the order data.  If you don't like the sound of that check out the aforementioned modules.

Let us know what you end up using! I'm curious about those modules but in this case I am going the custom route.